# Something very similar to predicate, but not a predicate

Tags: c#

I want to have a "predicate" (it's in quotes, since I don't know the right word), that returns different fields of an object, based on conditions. I hope a short example will illustrate.

```
 Predicate<MyClass> predicate
 if (condition1)
    predicate = x => x.Field1;
 else if (condition2)
     predicate = x => x.Field2;
foreach(vat item in ListOfItems)
{
    predicate(item) = someValue;//Here I am changing the value of that field.
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for a "property selector expression".

Comment: What if `Field1` and `Field2` have different types?

Comment: In my situation they are the same type.

Comment: @JasonYoung - no, i wanted to alter the value of the field.

Comment: What you want is a setter. `setter = (x, v) => { x.Field1 = v; };` and you use it like `setter(item, someValue);`

Comment: @RaymondChen and I can create a similar getter?

Comment: @RaymondChen could you please write an answer? With more details.

Comment: Your original code was a getter already. Your problem was that you were trying to use a getter as a setter.

Comment: @RaymondChen my code does not compile. So is yours.

Comment: Works for me. Obvious the setter is not a `Predicate<MyClass>` so you need to fix that.

Comment: A full example, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general term you're looking for is ["delegate"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx). While you can't directly do something like `predicate(item) = someValue;` in C#, you can use [`Action`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549311.aspx) and/or [`Func`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) to do what you're trying to do. Getting values is the more usual way of doing things, e.g. LINQ's [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) could be implemented like:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector
)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
        yield return selector(item);
}
```

And is used like:

```
myList.Select(x => x.Field1);
```

You could define something that can set properties, like this:

```
public static void SetAll<TSource, TProperty>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Action<TSource, TProperty> setter,
    TProperty someValue // example for how to get the value
)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        setter(item, someValue);
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
myList.SetAll((x, value) => x.Property1 = value, "New value");
// all Property1s are now "New value"
```

Or with something like your example:

```
Action<MyClass, string> predicate;
if (condition1)
    predicate = (x, value) => x.Property1 = value;
else
    predicate = (x, value) => x.Property2 = value;
foreach (var item in ListOfItems)
{
    predicate(item, someValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to go with this:

```
Func<MYClass, DateTime> f = null;
if (Condition1)
    f = x => x.Field1;
else if (condition2)
   f = x => x.Field2;
```